# No access to webinterface via activated openVPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I have a **LinkSys** Router with **OpenVPN** Server activated in the LinkSys admin interface.
The openVPN connections is working so far and I can access the Server via RDP and the internal IP-Address.

But I **can't** connect **via Browser to any web-interface**.
For example the routers admin interface or the web interface from a security system installed on the server.

If I type the server's IP adresse and the port number I get always:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

So the RDP connection or a ping to 192.168.1.2 is working but not the web-interface 192.168.1.2:8100 or the interface from the router on 192.168.1.1!

Can anybody help why this is not working?
Do I need any extra settings to acces Ports via activated openVPN?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the Windows Firewall on the Server.
After adding the port 8100 to the Windows Firewall the web interface is working.